# Is it possible to call methods of contract's initializer during its initialization?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I tried to deploy following smart contracts

```
pragma solidity 0.8.17;

contract Contract1 {
    constructor() {
        new Contract2(address(this));
    }

    function foo() public pure returns (string memory) {
        return "bar";
    }
}

contract Contract2 {
    Contract1 contract1;

    constructor(address _contract1) {
        contract1 = Contract1(_contract1);
        contract1.foo();
    }
}
```

but it fails with following message:

> The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The
> called function should be payable if you send value and the value you
> send should be less than your current balance. Debug the transaction
> to get more information.

Seems like it's impossible to call methods of contract's initializer (the contract that created an instance of current one) during its initialization.

My question is how it happens that address of the Contract1 is already exists, but it's impossible to call any of its methods from the constructor of Contract2?

Comment: that would just create an infinite loop 1 calls 2 which calls 1 which calls 2 etc....

Comment: @johnny5 ehm why should it create an infinite loop? Contract1(_contract1) only casts address type to Contract1 type, nothing more

Comment: Ahh, I stand corrected oops lol

Comment: You can fix this with the initializer pattern, they use it for creating proxys.  Just initialize the data after construction, and add `Owner.sol` or `AccessControl.sol` or make a static intializer using a boolean

Comment: Seems like initializer pattern is the best approach here

Answer (score 2):

The address of Contract1 is not yet available when the constructor of Contract2 is called. The address of Contract1 is only available after the constructor of Contract1 has finished executing.

This means that the constructor of Contract2 cannot call any methods of Contract1 until after the constructor of Contract1 has finished executing.

In this case you can deploy the Contract1, wait for the tx complete and after deploy the Contract2 using the address of Contract1 in constructor arguments.

Comment: But if the address of Contract1 is not available at the constructor of Contract 2, how comes that if I add a function that calls contract1.foo() to Contract2 everything works fine?

Comment: Yeah, you can pass the address as argument and will work

Comment: Other thing, if you need to know the address of the contract that will be deployed, you can deploy a deterministic smart contract on Ethereum. take a look at this article to see how implement this https://chainstack.com/deploying-a-deterministic-contract-on-ethereum/

Comment: So, looks like the address of contract exists, but there is no contract instance on that address till the constructor finishes its execution, right?

Comment: I think you are right, while the deploy transaction that executes the constructor is not completed this contract does not exist yet and cannot be used by the other